# unexpected output while trying to find prime numbers - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to get more familiar with Java, so trying out my own logic for the following  problem **Print all the prime numbers present in first 100 positive integers**...

```
import java.io.IOException;

class PrimeNumbers{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int[] num=new int[101];   //array to store values from 1 to 100
        int[] prime=new int[50];   //array to store prime numbers

        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++) 
            num[i]=i;     //add values from 1 to 100 to "num" array

        int i=1;      //index for "num" array
        int j=0;      //index for "prime" array
        int chk;      //temporary variable to store value from "num" to carry out all "checking operations"

        while(i<=100)
        {
            chk=num[i];
            if(chk==1)
            {
                prime[j++]=chk;
                i++;
                break;
            }
            else if(chk==2)
            {
                i++;
                break;
            }
            else if(chk==3)
            {
                prime[j++]=chk;  //increment i and j after adding the "chk" value to "prime" array 
                i++;
                break;
            }
            else if((chk % 2)!=0 && (chk % 3)!=0)   //if number is divisible by 2 or 3,no need to check further
            { 
                int k=4; 

                while(k<((chk+1)/2))   //check if value of "k" is less than half of "chk" value
                {
                    if(chk%k!=0) k++;   //increment "k" from 4 to half of chk's value and check if any of them is divisible
                }

                prime[j++]=chk;    
                i++;
                break;
            }   
            else
            i++;
        }
        for(int n=0;n<prime.length;n++)
            System.out.print(prime[n]+" "); //print the output
    }
}
```

The problem is that i'm not getting any errors,but the **output is not what i expected**,i've been trying for more than 3 hours to figure out the issue,but no luck..

any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**output :**
*1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0*

**EDIT**: ***Corrected version with similar logic***

```
import java.io.IOException;



class PrimeNumbers{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int[] prime=new int[50];   //array to store prime numbers
        int i=1;     
        int j=0;      //index for "prime" array
        int chk;      //temporary variable to store value i to carry out all "checking operations"

        while(i<=100)
        {
            chk=i;
            if(chk==1)
            {
                i++;
            }
            else if(chk==2)
            {
                prime[j++]=chk;  //increment i and j after adding the "chk" value to "prime" array 
                i++;
            }
            else if(chk==3)
            {
                prime[j++]=chk;  //increment i and j after adding the "chk" value to "prime" array 
                i++;
            }
            else if((chk % 2)!=0 && (chk % 3)!=0)   //if number is divisible by 2 or 3,no need to check further
            { 
                int k=5;
                boolean flag=false;
                while(k<(chk/2) && k<50)   //check if value of "k" is less than half of "chk" value
                {
                    if(chk%k!=0)
                    {
                        k++;         //increment "k" from 4 to half of chk's value and check if any of them is divisible
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        flag=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!flag)
                {
                 prime[j++]=chk;
                }
                i++;
            }   
            else
            {
            i++;
            }
        }
        for(int n=0;n<prime.length;n++)
            if(prime[n]!=0)
            System.out.print(prime[n]+" "); //print the output
    }
}
```

**Output:** 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97

Comment: Why on earth do you need an array for the numbers 1 - 100?

Comment: A better algorithm might be easier to implement... e.g. maintain a index of to the highest prime number you have printed so far (will start at 1) and an array of booleans which indicate that the specific number corresponding to the index of the number is prime (default all to true). Increment the index until you find a boolean that is true. Print that index. Loop through the remainder of the array setting every index'th boolean to false... lather rinse repeat

Comment: The num array is funny? Why do you need it? It just complicates your code. Instead of `num[i]` you can always just write `i`.

Comment: By the way: 1 is not a prime, by definition, but 2 is. Once we have this, we can say that any number > 2 is prime if and only if it is not divisible by any prime that is lower than that number.

Comment: thanks guys,learnt a lot!..will correct this and try a better logic..

Comment: good that you are trying, but also google it.

Answer (score 3):

`break` statement inside `if` block will break the `while` loop. So, remove all `break` statements within `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You break out of the loop when you put 1 in the list of primes:

```
    if(chk==1)
    {
        prime[j++]=chk;
        i++;
        break;
    }
```

Remove that (an other similar) breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Your  break; statement is the problem.

```
else if((chk % 2)!=0 && (chk % 3)!=0)   //if number is divisible by 2 or 3,no need to check further
{ 
    int k=4; 

    while(k<((chk+1)/2))   //check if value of "k" is less than half of "chk" value
    {
        if(chk%k!=0) k++;   //increment "k" from 4 to half of chk's value and check if any of them is divisible
     }
     prime[j++]=chk;    
     i++;
     break;  //here is the problem. you are breaking the outer loop
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array. There is an easier way.

Run a loop of numbers (x) and inside it another loop from 2 to half that x (y). If x is divisible by y then it's not a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `break` from your if block,as Break statement finishes execution of while loop

Trace For `i=0` ,

```
while(i<=100)
{
   chk=num[i]; // In num array num[i] = i, as assigned by you, so chk =1
   if(chk==1)   //chk==1 is true
   {
      prime[j++]=chk;  // j++ = 0 and then ++ ,so prime[0] = 1
      i++;
      break; // here your execution of while block finishes because of break
   }
   else if(chk==2){
      i++;
      break;
   }
.............
}
```

And in for loop first values i.e `prime[0] is 1`, except that `all values in prime is 
zero`.

```
for(int n=0;n<prime.length;n++)
        System.out.print(prime[n]+" "); // prime[0] = 1 & all other is zero.
```

That,s why you get such an absurd output

```
Use continue & not break
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program does not implement a prime algorithm at all.

Apart from the fact that you count 1 as prime but not 2, the core of your code is:

```
else if( something irrelevant ) { 
    int k=4;

    while( something ) {
        if(chk%k!=0) k++; 
    }

    prime[j++]=chk;    
    i++;
    break;
}
```

Just to point out two serious problems, without noting the other problems:

You go to great lengths to compute `k` in a while loop.
This while loop may never terminate, namely when `chk%k == 0`.
But then, after having risked your program running forever, you don't even use `k`!
Instead, you just include `chk` as a prime number.
Which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. First remove the breaks, they make you exit the while loop and remove the check for 1 (it is neither prime nor composite as per main stream)
2. To simplyfy your logic, you need to check if the number is divisible by 2 numbers[**LOGIC**: *A prime number is divisible by 1 and itself*] if so you can skip the number as not prime and go on with the next. 
   So your inner else if condition  "`else if((chk % 2)!=0 && (chk % 3)!=0)`" becomes

   `else if((chk % 2)!=0 && (chk % 3)!=0)`

   `{`

   ```
           int k=4;
           int flag=1;
           while((k<((chk+1)/2)))   //check if value of "k" is less than half of "chk" value
           {
               if(chk%k==0)
                   flag++;
               k++;   //increment "k" from 4 to half of chk's value and check if any of them is divisible
           }
           if(flag<2)
               prime[j++]=chk;    
           i++;
   ```

   `//                break;`
   `}`

3.Just think about this logic
All number divisible by 2 is not prime so you can increment your number by 2

if a number is not divisible by a prime number then it is a prime number

try this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int[] prime=new int[50];   //array to store prime numbers within 1-n prime numbers will be <=n/2
        int i=1;        //index for "num" array
        int j=1;        //index for storing to "prime" array
        int k=1;        //index for browsing through prime array
        prime[0]=2;     // setting the first element
        int flag=1;     // to check if a number is divisibe for than 2 times
        for(i=3;i<=100;i+=2) {
            for(k=0;prime[k]!=0;k++)    //browsing through the array to till non zero number is encountered
            {
                if(i%prime[k]==0) flag++;   //checking if the number is divisible, if so the flag is incremented 
            }
            if(flag<2)
            {
                prime[j++]=i;               // if the flag is still 1 then the number is a prime number
            }
            flag=1;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(prime)); //a short way to print an array
        }
```